# Sunspot search: Searching with negative keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sunspot

Hello I am using sunspot for searching:
when I say:

> keywords '"India" -"mountain"' do
>   minimum_match 1 end

It finds all the posts related to "India" keyword and which does not include "mountain" keyword.
But when I want all the posts globally which should not include "mountain" keyword how should i do that?
When tried with

> keywords '-"mountain"' do
>   minimum_match 1 end

It returned 0 results.

Is there any way that we will pass only negative filter value to sunspot and retrieve all the records except the passed keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a feature/limitation of solr/sunspot
but I have a workaround for this problem.

1. Index a field with string data type along with text as well
2. Indexing with text will help for keyword searching (as usual)
3. Add **AND** condition in the sunspot solr block which will have **without** method to escape the unwanted string in the search.

This will search with conditions (keyword specified **AND** without the escape string)